# Printing Name and value of configuration webapps of azure in powershell script

Tags: azure-powershell

I written some code in PowerShell script to print the configuration of one web app using azure portal. But I struck in between that exactly I want to print names and values in config of particular web app like development environment...

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass Connect-AzAccount $subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription Write-Host "Subscription:" MDD-NU-01 -Separator "" Set-AzContext -Subscription MDD-NU-01  $srcResourceGroup = "d1-sap-rg52" $srcAppName = "d1-sap-web-l521" $srcAppServer = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $srcResourceGroup -Name $srcAppName $srcAppSettings = $srcAppServer.SiteConfig.AppSettings`

1.uptohere its connecting in config appsettings
2.In appsetting there are names and value will there
3.After this i struck here the logic should give the output like print all the name and value in configuration of web app("d1-sap-web-l521")

Please anybody help me out.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the required information of WebApps using `Get-AzureRmWebApp`. Below is the script that worked for me.

```
$WebAppInfo = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName <YourResourceGroupName>  -Name <YourWebAppName>
$Configurations = $WebAppInfo.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$Configurations
```

**In portal:**

[image]

[image]